# Converting HH:MM:SS string in .csv to HH:MM:SS vector in R using hms()

Tags: r, time, types

How do you convert a string of times (*without dates*) in hh:mm:ss format from a .csv into a vector of times in the same format in R using the `hms()` package?

I have tried the following: `time <- as_hms(file$time)`
but I get the following error:
`Error: Lossy cast from <character> to <hms> at position(s) 140364, 140365, 140366, 140367, 140368, ... (and 2455 more)`.

The data are saved as hh:mm:ss time in the .csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parse_hms()` rather than `as_hms()`